# To check the key name like "item[ ]" exist in an object - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have an object named as "obj" and it has two keys named as "goal" and "item[]", ie.

```
var obj = {goal:"abc",item[]:"def"};
```

And these keys and values are created dynamically.

Problem -

I want to check if these keys exist or not. 
If I check

```
if(obj.goal != undefined){
   //Do something
}
```

then it gives desired output. but when I do

```
if(obj.item[] != undefined){
  //Do something
}
```

then it throw error(Syntax error). Please advice how to check with the second case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're just trying to check if a "key exists" then you can use `in`. e.g. `if('item[]' in obj) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
if (obj['item[]'] !== undefined) {
```